# How do you set autocommit in an SQL Server session?

Tags: sql-server, session, autocommit

How do you set autocommit in an SQL Server session?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can turn autocommit ON by setting implicit_transactions OFF:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
```

When the setting is ON, it returns to implicit transaction mode.  In implicit transaction mode, every change you make starts a transactions which you have to commit manually.

Maybe an example is clearer.  This will write a change to the database:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = 1 WHERE MyId = 1
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This will not write a change to the database:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = 1 WHERE MyId = 1
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

The following example will update a row, and then complain that there's no transaction to commit:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
UPDATE MyTable SET MyField = 1 WHERE MyId = 1
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Like Mitch Wheat said, autocommit is the default for Sql Server 2000 and up.

Answer (score 52):

I wanted a more permanent and quicker way. Because I tend to forget to add extra lines before writing my actual Update/Insert queries.

I did it by checking **SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS** check-box from Options.
To navigate to Options Select **Tools>Options>Query Execution>SQL Server>ANSI** in your Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Just make sure to execute `commit` or `rollback` after you are done executing your queries. Otherwise, the table you would have run the query will be locked for others.

Comment: I tried and I can confirm that it seems exactly the same as to write SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON, since it seems the more correct answer in 24 hours I will award with the bounty.

Comment: @hawkeye This should be the Accepted Answer.  The point of turning off Autocommit is to avoid mistakes, which changing the settings achieves. if one needs to remember to run `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` before running DML, one runs the risk of forgetting to start a transaction and running a statement which updates the database immediately. So the correct answer would be to always turn on transactions as this answer states.

Answer (score 10):

Autocommit is SQL Server's default transaction management mode. (SQL 2000 onwards)

Ref: [Autocommit Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

With SQLServer 2005 Express, what I found was that even with **autocommit off**, insertions into a Db table were committed without my actually issuing a commit command from the Management Studio session. The only difference was, when **autocommit was off, I could roll back all the insertions; with **autocommit on***, I could not.* 
**Actually, I was wrong.** With autocommit mode off, I see the changes only in the QA (Query Analyzer) window from which the commands were issued. If I popped a new QA (Query Analyzer) window, I do not see the changes made by the first window (session), i.e. they are NOT committed! I had to issue explicit commit or rollback commands to make changes visible to other sessions(QA windows) -- **my bad! Things are working correctly.**