# Nothing inserted in database?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following code, it executes without any error and even reports that 1 row was affected. However, nothing is saved. Why not?
i can retrieve from the database though.. but cannot write

```vb
Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection() 'The SQL Connection
SQLConn.ConnectionString = connstring 'Set the Connection String
SQLConn.Open()
Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand() 'The SQL Command
Dim SQLStr As String = "INSERT into region_table VALUES(10,23,4,'test')"
SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr 
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
SQLConn.Close()
```

SOLUTION::
Open right click on database connection in server explorer, Select Properties And use that Connection String! Hopes this solves anyone else's problem too :D

Comment: Do you have the same problem I did? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223223/sqlce-query-having-no-effect

Comment: Perhaps you need to commit the transaction?

Comment: Are you inserting into the right database?  You don't have a copy in Master by mistake or anything do you?

Comment: Also, who is the owner of the region_table?

Comment: What does your table `region_table` look like? Columns, datatypes etc. ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the connection to the command:

After this line:

```
SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr
```

add this one:

```
SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn
```

You should also use using statements to ensure everything is cleaned up correctly:

```
    Using SQLConn As New SqlConnection() 'The SQL Connection
        SQLConn.ConnectionString = connstring 'Set the Connection String
        SQLConn.Open()
        Using SQLCmd As New SqlCommand() 'The SQL Command
            Dim SQLStr As String = "INSERT into region_table VALUES(10,23,4,'test')"
            SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr
            SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn
            SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            SQLConn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: Is SQL case-sensitive?  Should it be `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: @user1137385: are there any exceptions thrown? The only way that this wouldn't write anything into the database is if an exception were being thrown. You can add a try/catch statement and/or walk through the code in debug to see where it is breaking. Any exception that is generated should give you a very good clue as to what is happening.

Comment: it's already in a try catch.
i found a similar code in a friend's program though... his code works fine! strange and frustrating! :-/

Comment: Are you sure you're writing to the correct database? If this is full sql server, you can run Sql Profile and see exactly what is getting written and to where. I find it extremely helpful in cases like this.

Comment: Yeah it was the wrong database! thnx for your help :)
wasted 1 day with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the database path in the connection string? XD