# SQL Transaction self-committing

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions, commit

I am running the following SQL Update Query in a transaction so that I can examine the results before committing. However, after executing and rolling back, I find that it has already committed and my data has changed despite never issuing a commit statement.

```
USE WS_Live
BEGIN TRAN Test

UPDATE AF
SET AF.AdditionalFieldsLookup11 = NULL

OUTPUT inserted.*

FROM dbo.Incident AS I

INNER JOIN dbo.AdditionalFields AS AF
ON AF.Oid = I.AdditionalFields

INNER JOIN dbo.AdditionalFieldsLookup11 AS AFL11
ON AFL11.Oid = AF.AdditionalFieldsLookup11

WHERE AF.AdditionalFieldsLookup11 IS NOT NULL
```

My statement was formatted properly and I did not lose any important data, but I would like to know why this is happening so that I don't run into problems in the future.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server roles out with auto-commit mode set to true by default.

[Here](http://suneethasdiary.wordpress.com/tag/disabling-auto-commit-mode-in-sql-server-management-studio/) is how to turn it off and here is a little additional detail regarding this feature:

- [MS Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213069%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [Working with autocommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090240/how-do-you-set-autocommit-in-an-sql-server-session)

Comment: I've done other transactions that I was able to rollback. Why would some work and not others?

Comment: From your first link it seems like my `BEGIN` should override the auto-commit. `A SQL Server connection operates in autocommit mode until a BEGIN TRANSACTION statement starts an explicit transaction, or implicit transaction mode is set on. `

Comment: Oh wait... I know what I did. Instead of putting `ROLLBACK TRAN Test` at the end of my SQL Query, I replaced `BEGIN` with `ROLLBACK`, so it effectively rolled back my previous transaction as if I had appended the command, and then proceeded to execute the entire query after the `ROLLBACK` line.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that SQL was doing exactly what I told it to when I tried to rollback my original transaction. Instead of appending `ROLLBACK` to the end of my transaction, I modified the `BEGIN TRAN Test` to `ROLLBACK TRAN Test` like this:

```
USE WS_Live
ROLLBACK TRAN Test

UPDATE AF
SET AF.AdditionalFieldsLookup11 = NULL

OUTPUT inserted.*

FROM dbo.Incident AS I

INNER JOIN dbo.AdditionalFields AS AF
ON AF.Oid = I.AdditionalFields

INNER JOIN dbo.AdditionalFieldsLookup11 AS AFL11
ON AFL11.Oid = AF.AdditionalFieldsLookup11

WHERE AF.AdditionalFieldsLookup11 IS NOT NULL
```

SQL acted as if I had appended `ROLLBACK TRAN Test` to the end of my previous query, and then appended an additional query on the end of that.